# tcl/tk treeview - get the id of the node being clicked

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

in this sample program, I can get all kinds of information, but is there an easy way to know the `id` of the row that was clicked?

```
#! /usr/bin/env wish

ttk::treeview .tree -selectmode none

.tree tag bind clickable <ButtonRelease> {
  puts "%W %X %Y %K %b %d %A %K"
}

.tree configure -height 2

.tree insert {} end -id A -text A -tags clickable
.tree insert {} end -id B -text B -tags clickable

pack .tree
```

[image]

output:

```
$ ./row-click.tcl 
.tree 894 407 ?? 1 ?? ?? ??
.tree 894 407 ?? 1 ?? ?? ??
.tree 893 431 ?? 1 ?? ?? ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `.tree identify item $x $y` where `$x` and `$y` are the coordinates does just that. In a bound script the tree name is better to be specified as `%W`, and the coordinates as `%x` and `%y` (coordinates with respect to the widget itself):

```
#! /usr/bin/env wish

ttk::treeview .tree -selectmode none

.tree tag bind clickable <ButtonRelease> {
  puts [%W identify item %x %y]
}

.tree configure -height 2

.tree insert {} end -id A -text A -tags clickable
.tree insert {} end -id B -text B -tags clickable

pack .tree
```